# AngularJs controller is not registered when importing in es6 module

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm refactoring old code and shifting to a modular pattern with Webpack, where the AngularJs application consumes smaller modules, which are required on different views.

core bundle (works fine)

```
// initializes app, with global deps
import myModule from './path';
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', [myModule]);  
angular.bootstrap(document, [myApp]);
```

sub-module - available in a separate bundle to the above

```
// mySubModule.js
import myController from './sub-sub-path';
const subModule = angular.module('mySubModule').controller('myController', myController);
export default 'mySubModule';

// import subModule and add as dependency in myApp
import mySubModule from './sub-path';
angular.module('myApp').requires.push(mySubModule);
```

Debugging shows myController in the invokeQueue array on the sub module, and the sub module referenced as a dependency in myApp, yet the controller is not registered? What have I missed?

EDIT: pretty sure this is due to me adding the module after bootstrapping the application. Can I lazy load a module?

Comment: Where is 'mySubModule' defined?

Comment: I was thinking about this backwards - rather than trying to add the module post-bootstrap, I instead simply shifted the bootstrapping to after all modules were created. All working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this backwards - rather than trying to add the module post-bootstrap, I instead simply shifted the bootstrapping to after all modules were created. All working fine.